# Netplan apply fails on udevadm settle during 20.04 autoinstaller

Tags: 20.04, netplan, udev, subiquity, curtin

During execution of the [network](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#network) section of the new Subiquity server autoinstaller it fails with a non-zero return code on `netplan apply`, which in turn runs `udevadm settle -t 0` over and over again which returns exit code 1 until it finally gives up.

From a `/var/crash` report:

```sh
# date/time removed for readability
DEBUG subiquitycore.netplan:111 config for ens2f0 = {}
DEBUG subiquitycore.netplan:111 config for ens2f0 = {}
DEBUG subiquitycore.netplan:135 config for bond0 = 
    {'dhcp4': True, 'interfaces': ['ens2f0', 'ens2f1'], 'parameters': {'lacp-rate': 'slow', 'mode': '802.3ad', 'transmit-hash-policy', 'layer2'}}
DEBUG subiquitycore.utils:74 arun_command called: ['netplan', 'apply']
DEBUG subiquitycore.utils:48 run_command called: ['udevadm', 'settle', '-t', '0']
DEBUG subiquitycore.utils:61 ['udevadm', 'settle', '-t', '0'] exited with code 1
DEBUG subiquitycore.controller.network:196 waiting 0.1 to let udev event queue settle
<repeating udevadm settle commands issued>
```

(Relevant) autoinstall config:

```yaml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1

  # double network due to a bug
  # see https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#network
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        ens2f0: {}
        ens2f1: {}
      bonds:
        bond0:
          dhcp4: true
          interfaces:
            - ens2f0
            - ens2f1
          parameters:
            mode: 802.3ad
            lacp-rate: slow
            transmit-hash-policy: layer2
```

Which generates the following Netplan configuration (`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`):

```yaml
# This is network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: true
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        lacp-rate: slow
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2
  ethernets:
    ens2f0: {}
    ens2f1: {}
  version: 2
```

I've also tried with a simpler netplan config with just a static address on one port (`ens2f0`), or even the default which runs DHCPv4 on any interface matching `eth*` or `en*` (in this case `ens2f0` and `ens2f1`).

**My theory** is that there's a module or something that creates an unhandled and maybe even unrelated event in udev, but how would I go about debugging this?

Moreover, isn't it a big aggressive of Netplan to never continue if there's such unhandled events in udev, even if the relevant devices and interfaces are correctly configured?

---

**Setup:**
Ubuntu 20.04 daily build 20200923 (tried 20.04.1 and the inital LTS release as well)
Netplan 0.99-ubuntuu3~20.04.2
Systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.2

Supermicro X11DDW-L
Mellanox ConnectX-5 (PCI-E)
BIOS/Legacy boot (due to incompatibilities between this NIC/motherboard in UEFI)

Comment: Why BIOS/Legacy boot? What .yaml file are you showing us? It contains two "network:" lines. Can you please show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @heynnema I've not been able to trigger PXE boot with this NIC when the server is configured using UEFI, from what I've gathered they don't seem to play together nicely, but that's a seperate issue.. :) The YAML is the initial layout and network section of the autoinstaller config, and it contains two `network` definitions due to a bug with the 20.04 GA release ([source](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#network)). I'll come back to you with some generated Netplan configuration files.

Comment: FYI: https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle Does this apply to you?

Comment: If you're referring to my UEFI/PXE issue I don't think it does, it's an issue of the NIC's ROM not even registering as an option in UEFI. To confirm whether or not it should be supported has been tricky even talking to vendor support, which is why I've been concentrating on BIOS booting for now.

Comment: I've updated my post with the generated Netplan configuration, but more interestingly the issue seems to be somehow related to the [storage](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#storage) section as I was able to complete the autoinstaller now with only a different storage configuration. When failing I've been using a custom layout written "by hand", while when it succeeded I used a configuration generated to `/var/log/installer/autoinstall` from a previous interactive install. In essence they do the same, but using different match specs etc. More to come.

Comment: I'll have to come back to this tomorrow, as it's not immediately obvious what in the `storage` configuration is different and that could trigger it, and as its it's quite verbose it'll take some time to go through and clean up/share here.

Comment: Google "Mellanox ConnectX-5 firmware update". Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not really matter if I use BIOS or UEFI booting on these servers so I won't be digging much more into why that part didn't work. Cheers for the enthusiasm though. The root cause has been found and solved now as well, so I'm a happy camper now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be due to an error in my
[storage](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#storage)
section of the autoinstaller config, and not really due to Netplan per se.

My server has 2 disks that I wanted to configure in a software RAID using
`mdadm`. Since I'm using BIOS boot and a gpt partition table I created a 1MB
un-formatted partition for grub on each of my drives as adviced in the
[curtin documentation](https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html#partition-command).

> If the host system for curtin has been booted using UEFI then curtin will
> install grub to the esp partition. If the system installation media has been
> booted using an MBR, grub will be installed onto the disk’s MBR. **However,
> on a disk with a gpt partition table, there is not enough space after the MBR
> for grub to store its second stage core.img, so a small un-formatted
> partition with the *bios_grub* flag is needed. This partition should be placed
> at the beginning of the disk and should be 1MB in size.** It should not
> contain a filesystem or be mounted anywhere on the system.

In addition to this however I erroneously assumed that I had to create a RAID
for these 1MB partitions as well, which is not necessary. The error message
that had eluded me was found in the syslog (`curtin_log.<pid>` identifier), and
not mentioned in the regular subiquity logs (`/var/log/installer` and
`/var/crash`). It could also be seen in curtin's own logs (`/var/log/curtin`)
which I was previously unaware of.

```sh
# /var/log/curtin/install.log
# wrapped for readability
An error occured handling 'md0-bios-boot': ProcessExecutionError - 
    Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['mdadm', '--create', '/dev/md0', '--run',
    '--metadata=default', '--homehost=ubuntu-server', '--level=raid1',
    '--raid-devices=2', '/dev/sda1', '/dev/sdb1']
Exit code: 1
Reason: -
Stdout: ''
Stderr: mdadm: no free space left on /dev/sda1
        mdadm: no free space left on /dev/sdb1
        mdadm: create aborted

finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: configuring raid: md0-bios-boot
<some more noise from curtin>
```

This seems to have triggered an unhandled udev event and the reason why
`udevadm settle` returns with exit code 1, halting Netplan and the installer.
Odd how the exit code 1 from `mdadm` in curtin wasn't enough to also crash it
before it got to Netplan.

---

Removing this part of my storage config fixed the problem,

```yaml
- id: md0-bios-boot
  type: raid
  preserve: false
  raidlevel: 1
  devices:
    - sda-bios-boot
    - sdb-bios-boot
  name: md0
  ptable: gpt
```

The full storage config:

```yaml
storage:
  config:
    - id: disk-sda
      type: disk
      preserve: false
      ptable: gpt
      wipe: superblock
      grub_device: true
      path: /dev/sda

    - id: disk-sdb
      type: disk
      preserve: false
      ptable: gpt
      wipe: superblock
      grub_device: true
      path: /dev/sdb

    - id: sda-bios-boot
      type: partition
      preserve: false
      device: disk-sda
      number: 1
      size: 1MB
      flag: bios_grub

    - id: sdb-bios-boot
      type: partition
      preserve: false
      device: disk-sdb
      number: 1
      size: 1MB
      flag: bios_grub

    # NOTE: part that had to be removed
    - id: md0-bios-boot
      type: raid
      preserve: false
      raidlevel: 1
      devices:
        - sda-bios-boot
        - sdb-bios-boot
      name: md0
      ptable: gpt

    - id: sda-root
      type: partition
      preserve: false
      device: disk-sda
      number: 2
      size: -1

    - id: sdb-root
      type: partition
      preserve: false
      device: disk-sdb
      number: 2
      size: -1

    - id: md1-os
      type: raid
      preserve: false
      raidlevel: 1
      devices:
        - sda-root
        - sdb-root
      name: md1
      ptable: gpt

    - id: md1-os-rootfs
      type: format
      preserve: false
      volume: md1-os
      fstype: ext4

    - id: mount-rootfs
      type: mount
      device: md1-os-rootfs
      path: /
```